# Concatenate all previous row values from a TEXT column in reverse order

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, recursive

My Postgres version is 11.15. I have a table like:

| id | employee |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna |
| 2 | Bill |
| 3 | Carol |
| 4 | Dave |
| 5 | Tom |

The output I need is

| id | cumulative_employees |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna |
| 2 | Bill, Anna |
| 3 | Carol, Bill, Anna |
| 4 | Dave, Carol, Bill, Anna |
| 5 | Tom, Dave, Carol, Bill, Anna |

I tried using LAG function of PostgreSQL but it only gives me last row value, could not find a way to get all previous rows, number of rows is dynamic and can be anywhere between 12 to 52 rows.

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the inverted order of elements in the aggregated string, something like this would do:

```
SELECT id
     , string_agg(employee, ', ') OVER (ORDER BY id DESC
                                        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ApBJsfgf)

Aggregate functions allow a local per-group `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT string_agg(employee, ', ' ORDER BY id DESC) AS cumulative_employees
FROM   tbl;
```

But the same is not implemented for window functions. Hence the "trick" with shifted window frames to achieve the same.